# Any advantages of hover over mouseover in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to JQuery API.
I have been using mouseover, but I have never used hover before.
SO I am wondering if I should use hover instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) binds two handlers for the events [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter)  and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave), so it is a more convenient way and also easier to understand the purpose.

`mouseenter` differs from [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) so far as `mouseenter` **is not** fired if the cursor is over/enters a child element of the element the handler is bound to.
It is only fired once, when the cursors enters the element. `mouseover` is always fired, even if the cursor is over a child element.

The best way to see the difference is to have a look at the example of [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/#example-0).

Furthermore, `mouseover` and `mouseout` are real JavaScript events whereas `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are events provided by jQuery (afaik).

**In the end, it depends on what you want to achieve.** There is no right or wrong and all these methods have their purpose. Unless you show some code, there is not much more to say.

---

If you mean `:hover` in CSS and you can achieve the desired effect with it, go for it. If there is a non-JS solution for a certain problem, always choose this one.

Answer (score 2):

`hover` just saves you from having to do both a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave` by doing both in one function.

Answer (score 1):

i prefer use css hover, because seems that I write less code to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

They're the same, except hover handles both mouseenter and mouseleave

See: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

So you can use it like this

```
$('selector').hover(function () {
    // Do stuff on mouse enter
  }, function () {
    // Do other stuff on mouse leave
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning, here is another equivalent to using hover:

```
$('selector').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
 if (event.type == "mouseenter") {
  // MouseEnter code
 } else {
  // MouseLeave code
 }
})
```